# codename1 project tab componets , my codename1 project changes behaviour from no where

Tags: css, codenameone

codename1 project tab components

```
        Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Tab");
        FontImage icon1 = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_ADD_A_PHOTO, s);
        FontImage icon2 = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_WATCH, s);
        FontImage icon3 = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_QUESTION_ANSWER, s);

        Container container1 = BoxLayout.encloseY(oders.Oders());
        Container container2 = BoxLayout.encloseY(home.Home());
        Container container3 = BoxLayout.encloseY(me.Me());

        hometabs.addTab("Oders", icon1, container1);
        hometabs.addTab("Home", icon2, container2);
        hometabs.addTab("Me", icon3, container3);
```

[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VIf4.png), my codename1 project changes behavior from nowhere

Comment: I've just edited your question to fix the formatting and making the screenshot link working. However, I didn't understand your question: what's the issue?

Comment: according to the screenshot, my tabs cant align in the normal way

Comment: Is your code like this? https://gist.github.com/jsfan3/fa1cfc0da96f6dd0b094ef064fb06296 Or are there differences?

Comment: yes please, like everything was ok and I was going on creating other classes then meanwhile running my code, but after some time this happened... from no where

Comment: I had to create a new project

Comment: Did you send a build? Did you do it in the new project?
Did you run an update project libs?

Comment: yah I did all that ..